# PHP prints out 1,458 MYSQL jquery 1072

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, select

I am not sure why, but when I run the following MySQL query it returns 1458 results. It then puts those results in a JSON format, which my jQuery script then outputs, but for some reason it is only returning 1072 and also takes around 15 seconds for it to show. Included is the jQuery script I made.

```
SELECT
    customer.customer_id,
    customer.HQStatus,
    date_format(customer.CreatedTime, '%d-%m-%Y') as CreatedTime,
    date_format(customer.ModifiedDate, '%d-%m-%Y') as ModifiedDate,
    customer.AMStatus,
    customer.LeadOwnerId,
    customer.Company,
    customer.TradingName,
    customer.FirstName,
    customer.LastName,
    customer.LeadStatus,
    customer.Phone,
    customer.Email,
    user.firstname as stafffirstname,
    user.lastname as stafflastname
FROM
    customer_detail as customer,
    admin_userlogin as user
WHERE user.id = customer.LeadOwnerId
ORDER BY customer.CreatedTime DESC
```

jQuery code is a little big:

```
function listallleads(){
$.getScript('js/quicksearch.js', function(data, textStatus){});
    $.getScript('js/cornz.js', function(data, textStatus){});




    numberofleads = null;   

    $.getJSON('system/classes/core.php?task=listmyleads&userid='+userid+'&usertype='+usertype+'&callback=?', function(dataleads) {

      $.each(dataleads,function(i, myleads){
        numberofleads = i;
        var businessname = "";
        if(myleads.Company == null || myleads.Company == "null" || myleads.Company == "")
        {
        businessname = myleads.TradingName; 
        }
        else
        {
        businessname = myleads.Company;
        }



            if(myleads.ho > 1)
            {
                myleads.ho = "Complete";
            }
            else
            {
                myleads.ho = "Pending"; 
            }
            if(myleads.AMStatus == "1")
            {
            myleads.AMStatus = "Confirmed"; 
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "3")
            {
            myleads.AMStatus = "Canceled";  
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "4")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Does Not Have Mobile";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "5")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Not Contactable";   
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "6")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Re-Send Welcome Pack";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "7")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Welcome Pack Sent";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "8")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Swipe Confirmed";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "9")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Refussed Banking Details";
            }
            else
            {
            myleads.AMStatus = "Not Confirmed"; 
            }





            leadstatus = leadstatusselect(myleads.LeadStatus);


        if(myleads.AMStatus == "1")
        {
            myleads.AMStatus = "one";
        }

        if(myleads.AMStatus == "3")
        {
            myleads.AMStatus = "red";
        }


        if(myleads.HQStatus == 0)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "Please Select";
        }
        else if(myleads.HQStatus == 2)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "iNcard Loaded $1";
        }
        else if(myleads.HQStatus == 3)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "iNcard Loaded $5";
        }
        else if(myleads.HQStatus == 4)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "Terminal Verified";
        }


        var s = myleads.Phone;
        s = s.replace('(', '');
        s = s.replace(')', '');
        s = s.replace(/ /g, '');
        myleads.Phone = s;
        //alert(s);

        cssstats = "lead"+myleads.AMStatus;


            $("tbody").append('<tr id="'+myleads.customer_id+'" class="'+cssstats+'">'+
'           <td id="row" class="small"><input id="'+myleads.customer_id+'" type="checkbox"></td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.CreatedTime+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.stafffirstname+'</td>'+
'           <td class="companysize">'+businessname+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.FirstName+' '+myleads.LastName+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.Phone+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field" class="leadstatus">'+leadstatus+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">'+myleads.AMStatus+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">'+myleads.HQStatus+'</td>'+
'           <td class="bigger temail">'+myleads.Email+'</td>'+
'           <td class="last field">'+myleads.ModifiedDate+'</td>'+
'       </tr>');


      });
        qs.cache();
    });


    if(usertype == 3)
    {
    leadtype = "A/M Status";    
    }
    else
    {
    leadtype = "Lead Status";   
    }

    $("#todo_bg").hide();
    $("#menuarea").html('<a id="gotohome"><div id="backmain" class="backbg">Back</div></a><div id="nav" class="backbgright">Manage Business Lead</div>'+
                        '<div id="dowithleads"><button id="selectall" class="blackbutton export"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkall" value="Yes" style="float:left;">Select All</button><button id="editlisting" class="blackbutton manage">Edit Listing</button><button id="sendemailout" class="blackbutton manage">Send Message</button> <button id="deletelead" class="blackbutton manage">Delete Lead</button>'+
                        '<div id="searchbox"><input type="text" name="search" value="" id="searchleads" placeholder="Search" autofocus /></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div id="dowithleads" style="width:980px; overflow:scroll;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="sortable paginated scrollTable" id="manageleads" style="text-align:left;">'+
'   <thead class="fixedHeader">'+
'       <tr>'+
'           <th class="small" id="first"></th>'+
'           <th class="field" class="ui-tableFilter-date">Created</th>'+
'           <th class="field">Lead Owner</th>'+
'           <th class="companysize">Trading Name</th>'+
'           <th class="field">Customer Name</th>'+
'           <th class="field">Phone No.</th>'+
'           <th class="field" class="leadstatus">Lead Status</th>'+
'           <th class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">A/M Status</th>'+
'           <th class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">H/Q Status</th>'+
'           <th id="emails" class="bigger">Email</th>'+
'           <th class="field">Mod Date</th>'+
'       </tr>'+
'   </thead>'+
'   <tbody class="scrollContent"></tbody>'+
'</table></div><div id="noloeads" style="float:right; margin:5px;"></div>');  


    if(usertype == 1 || usertype == 3 || usertype == 4)
    {
    $("#dowithleads").append('<button id="printlisting" class="blackbutton manage">Print W/P Letter</button>'); 
    }

    if(usertype == 1 || usertype == 3 || usertype == 4)
    {
    $("#dowithleads").append('<button id="exportlisting" class="blackbutton export">Export</button>');      
    }

    if(usertype == 1)
    {
        $('.hostatus').show();
    }
    if(usertype ==3)
    {
        $('.hostatus').show();  
        $('.leadstatus').hide();
    }



    var script = document.createElement('link');
    script.href = 'theme/style/manageleads.css';
    script.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    script.type = 'text/css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8) {
        var script = document.createElement('link');
        script.href = 'theme/style/ie-manageleads.css';
        script.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        script.type = 'text/css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        $("table").tableFilter({ dialog: { modal: false } });
                        updatecounter(numberofleads);
                        },90);
    var qs = $('input#searchleads').quicksearch('table#manageleads tbody tr');
    },2000);


}
```

Comment: You're expecting 1458 rows, and you're getting 1072 in the final output in the browser, but I can't tell from your question _when_ you think the other rows are disappearing. How sure are you that the JSON output from your PHP contains all 1458 rows? Can you log it on the server to confirm? In your JS Ajax callback function if you `alert(dataleads.length);` what do you get?

Comment: That is returning 1464 > We have added rows today

Comment: What is returning 1464? The `alert(dataleads.length);` that I suggested you (temporarily) add to your JS Ajax callback function, or something earlier in the process?

Comment: Yes the alert(dataleads.length) is 1464.

Comment: Is there away to do the first 20 rows and then show them and then continue til they are all loaded

Comment: Wait, let's not introduce new requirements until you've confirmed that the original problem is gone. Is it now displaying all 1464 rows? If the alert gives 1464 but they don't all display then something is wrong somewhere in your `$.each()` - if there are still rows missing are they all missing from the bottom of list or are they missing here and there from random spots throughout the list?

Comment: they are all missing from the bottom of the list. I made a loop so check for new leads and now it seems to work fine. it stops at 1088 and then goes to the next checknewleads function and then it seems to show the rest of the leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by the following. I will say this is NOT the best way to do it.

```
function listallleads(){
$.getScript('js/quicksearch.js', function(data, textStatus){});
    $.getScript('js/cornz.js', function(data, textStatus){});

    var number;



    $.getJSON('system/classes/core.php?task=listmyleads&userid='+userid+'&usertype='+usertype+'&callback=?', function(dataleads) {
    number = dataleads.length;
    $.each(dataleads,function(i, myleads){
        numberofleads = i;
        var businessname = "";
        if(myleads.Company == null || myleads.Company == "null" || myleads.Company == "")
        {
        businessname = myleads.TradingName; 
        }
        else
        {
        businessname = myleads.Company;
        }



            if(myleads.ho > 1)
            {
                myleads.ho = "Complete";
            }
            else
            {
                myleads.ho = "Pending"; 
            }
            if(myleads.AMStatus == "1")
            {
            myleads.AMStatus = "Confirmed"; 
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "3")
            {
            myleads.AMStatus = "Canceled";  
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "4")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Does Not Have Mobile";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "5")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Not Contactable";   
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "6")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Re-Send Welcome Pack";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "7")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Welcome Pack Sent";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "8")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Swipe Confirmed";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "9")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Refussed Banking Details";
            }
            else
            {
            myleads.AMStatus = "Not Confirmed"; 
            }





            leadstatus = leadstatusselect(myleads.LeadStatus);


        if(myleads.AMStatus == "1")
        {
            myleads.AMStatus = "one";
        }

        if(myleads.AMStatus == "3")
        {
            myleads.AMStatus = "red";
        }


        if(myleads.HQStatus == 0)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "Please Select";
        }
        else if(myleads.HQStatus == 2)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "iNcard Loaded $1";
        }
        else if(myleads.HQStatus == 3)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "iNcard Loaded $5";
        }
        else if(myleads.HQStatus == 4)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "Terminal Verified";
        }


        var s = myleads.Phone;
        s = s.replace('(', '');
        s = s.replace(')', '');
        s = s.replace(/ /g, '');
        myleads.Phone = s;
        //alert(s);

        cssstats = "lead"+myleads.AMStatus;


            $("tbody").append('<tr id="'+myleads.customer_id+'" class="'+cssstats+'">'+
'           <td id="row" class="small"><input id="'+myleads.customer_id+'" type="checkbox"></td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.CreatedTime+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.stafffirstname+'</td>'+
'           <td class="companysize">'+businessname+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.FirstName+' '+myleads.LastName+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.Phone+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field" class="leadstatus">'+leadstatus+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">'+myleads.AMStatus+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">'+myleads.HQStatus+'</td>'+
'           <td class="bigger temail">'+myleads.Email+'</td>'+
'           <td class="last field">'+myleads.ModifiedDate+'</td>'+
'       </tr>');
      });

    qs.cache();

    });

    setTimeout(function(){  

                        var n = $('tbody tr:not(.ui-tableFilter-hidden)').size();


                        checknewleads(n,number);

                        },7000);

    if(usertype == 3)
    {
    leadtype = "A/M Status";    
    }
    else
    {
    leadtype = "Lead Status";   
    }

    $("#todo_bg").hide();
    $("#menuarea").html('<a id="gotohome"><div id="backmain" class="backbg">Back</div></a><div id="nav" class="backbgright">Manage Business Lead</div>'+
                        '<div id="dowithleads"><div style="width:100px;float:left;"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkall" value="Yes" style="float:left;">Select All</div><button id="editlisting" class="blackbutton manage">Edit Listing</button><button id="sendemailout" class="blackbutton manage">Send Message</button> <button id="deletelead" class="blackbutton manage">Delete Lead</button>'+
                        '<div id="searchbox"><input type="text" name="search" value="" id="searchleads" placeholder="Search" autofocus /></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div id="dowithleads" style="width:980px; overflow:scroll;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="sortable paginated scrollTable" id="manageleads" style="text-align:left;">'+
'   <thead class="fixedHeader">'+
'       <tr>'+
'           <th class="small" id="first"></th>'+
'           <th class="field" class="ui-tableFilter-date">Created</th>'+
'           <th class="field">Lead Owner</th>'+
'           <th class="companysize">Trading Name</th>'+
'           <th class="field">Customer Name</th>'+
'           <th class="field">Phone No.</th>'+
'           <th class="field" class="leadstatus">Lead Status</th>'+
'           <th class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">A/M Status</th>'+
'           <th class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">H/Q Status</th>'+
'           <th id="emails" class="bigger">Email</th>'+
'           <th class="field">Mod Date</th>'+
'       </tr>'+
'   </thead>'+
'   <tbody class="scrollContent"></tbody>'+
'</table></div><div id="noloeads" style="float:right; margin:5px;"></div>');  


    if(usertype == 1 || usertype == 3 || usertype == 4)
    {
    $("#dowithleads").append('<button id="printlisting" class="blackbutton manage">Print W/P Letter</button>'); 
    }

    if(usertype == 1 || usertype == 3 || usertype == 4)
    {
    $("#dowithleads").append('<button id="exportlisting" class="blackbutton export">Export</button>');      
    }

    if(usertype == 1)
    {
        $('.hostatus').show();
    }
    if(usertype ==3)
    {
        $('.hostatus').show();  
        $('.leadstatus').hide();
    }



    var script = document.createElement('link');
    script.href = 'theme/style/manageleads.css';
    script.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    script.type = 'text/css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8) {
        var script = document.createElement('link');
        script.href = 'theme/style/ie-manageleads.css';
        script.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        script.type = 'text/css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        $("table").tableFilter({ dialog: { modal: false } });
                        //updatecounter(numberofleads);
                        },90);
    var qs = $('input#searchleads').quicksearch('table#manageleads tbody tr');
    },2000);


}


function checknewleads(a,e)
{
    a = a+1;
    $.getJSON('system/classes/core.php?task=checkmyleads&fromid='+a+'&toid='+e+'&userid='+userid+'&usertype='+usertype+'&callback=?', function(dataleadstwo) {                

      $.each(dataleadstwo,function(i, myleads){
        numberofleads = i;
        var businessname = "";
        if(myleads.Company == null || myleads.Company == "null" || myleads.Company == "")
        {
        businessname = myleads.TradingName; 
        }
        else
        {
        businessname = myleads.Company;
        }



            if(myleads.ho > 1)
            {
                myleads.ho = "Complete";
            }
            else
            {
                myleads.ho = "Pending"; 
            }



            if(myleads.AMStatus == "1")
            {
            myleads.AMStatus = "Confirmed"; 
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "3")
            {
            myleads.AMStatus = "Canceled";  
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "4")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Does Not Have Mobile";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "5")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Not Contactable";   
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "6")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Re-Send Welcome Pack";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "7")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Welcome Pack Sent";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "8")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Swipe Confirmed";
            }
            else if(myleads.AMStatus == "9")
            {
                myleads.AMStatus = "Refussed Banking Details";
            }
            else
            {
            myleads.AMStatus = "Not Confirmed"; 
            }



            leadstatus = leadstatusselect(myleads.LeadStatus);


        if(myleads.AMStatus == "1")
        {
            myleads.AMStatus = "one";
        }

        if(myleads.AMStatus == "3")
        {
            myleads.AMStatus = "red";
        }


        if(myleads.HQStatus == 0)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "Please Select";
        }
        else if(myleads.HQStatus == 2)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "iNcard Loaded $1";
        }
        else if(myleads.HQStatus == 3)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "iNcard Loaded $5";
        }
        else if(myleads.HQStatus == 4)
        {
            myleads.HQStatus = "Terminal Verified";
        }


        var s = myleads.Phone;
        s = s.replace('(', '');
        s = s.replace(')', '');
        s = s.replace(/ /g, '');
        myleads.Phone = s;
        //alert(s);

        cssstats = "lead"+myleads.AMStatus;


            $("tbody").append('<tr id="'+myleads.customer_id+'" class="'+cssstats+'">'+
'           <td id="row" class="small"><input id="'+myleads.customer_id+'" type="checkbox"></td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.CreatedTime+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.stafffirstname+'</td>'+
'           <td class="companysize">'+businessname+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.FirstName+' '+myleads.LastName+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field">'+myleads.Phone+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field" class="leadstatus">'+leadstatus+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">'+myleads.AMStatus+'</td>'+
'           <td class="field" class="hostatus" style="display:hidden;">'+myleads.HQStatus+'</td>'+
'           <td class="bigger temail">'+myleads.Email+'</td>'+
'           <td class="last field">'+myleads.ModifiedDate+'</td>'+
'       </tr>');

      });
        qs.cache();
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        $("table").tableFilter({ dialog: { modal: false } });
                        updatecounter(numberofleads);
                        },90);
    var qs = $('input#searchleads').quicksearch('table#manageleads tbody tr');
    },2000);
}
```